# Page life cycle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm implementing `INavigation` in my MVVM Light Toolkit based Windows WPF application. This is implementation of NavigateTo:

```
private Frame GetFrame()
{
    return (Application.Current.MainWindow as Generator.MainWindow).MainFrame; ;
}

public void NavigateTo(string pageKey)
{
    CurrentPageKey = pageKey;
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(_keyPageTypeMapping[pageKey]);
    GetFrame()?.Navigate(obj);
}
```

When I navigate to new page, the new page is created and displayed. However, when I navigate away, I don't see that the old page's destructor has been called. Even after 10-20 navigations I don't see it. I only see desctructor is called after I exit application. Question is what is the best way to dispose old page?

Comment: Do you mean `Dispose` or the _finalizer_?  Do you _need_ to dispose of it?  what resources is the page holding on to that need disposing?

Comment: I suppose Dispose, because I don't care about finalizing. Just need some sign that the objects are not retained somewhere. The resources are UI objects mostly, but when stacking in memory, could be costly.

Comment: Unless your form used unmanaged resources, or managed resources that implement `IDisposable`, there's nothing for you to do, other than to trust the Garbage collector to do its job.  It releases objects from memory _when it needs to_.

Comment: If I am creating N pages, then on application exit should I see destructor called N times? (considering that I haven't seen destructor called at all during app lifetime)

Comment: What are you looking at to determine that?  There is no "destructor" in C#. Classes have a finalizer (which doesn't do anything unless it's overridden) and can implement the Dispose pattern.  The Garbage Collector doesn't always run during an app's lifetime - it will only run if there is memory pressure and will _try_ to run when the app is not "busy".  It's _possible_ that something is keeping a reference to your form and not releasing it, but you should be able to determine that - look for places where a reference to your form is held and see if it is released appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should be fine. If the Garbage Collector has not disposed of the pages yet then there hasn't been a need to do so yet.  If you are concerned with if these old pages can be Garbage Collected, or if you just want to force the collection to happen.  Try explicitly calling the Garbage collector with:

```
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: `GC.Collect()` didn't force object to be destroyed. I have some guess that those objects are not really disposed of due to Navigation eco-system. On top of my window an IE7 style navigation is appearing, with back/forw. buttons. Probably framework need them alive? Creating so many new objects without single dispose sign bothers me...